# Unable to build gnome-builder using JHBuild

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, jhbuild

I am trying to build `gnome-builder` code on Ubuntu 12.04  using JHBuild, but JHBuild is giving some errors:

1) on running `jhbuild sanitycheck`

```
checkout root (~/jhbuild/checkout) is not writable
Could not find DocBook XML DTD V4.1.2 in XML catalog
Could not find DocBook XSL Stylesheets in XML catalog
```

I have tried to install all possible dependencies I could.

2) Also `jhbuild sysdeps --install` shows:

```
list of dependencies ..
jhbuild sysdeps: Don't know how to install packages on this system
```

3) When I try to build it as shown below:

```
jhbuild -m gnome-world build gnome-builder
```

it shows:

```
jhbuild build: failed to parse /usr/share/jhbuild/modulesets/gnome-apps-3.20.modules: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/usr/share/jhbuild/modulesets/gnome-apps-3.20.modules'
```

I have pasted sample `jhbuildrc` file in home dir as earlier it was showing

```
unable to load config file ~/.jhbuildrc not found
```

Comment: jhbuild does not know all package systems. e.g. on arch linux you need to install packages yourself, searching .pc files with pkgfile.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you followed manual how to [install JHBuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/unstable/getting-started.html.en#getting-started-install). After

```
$ jhbuild sanitycheck
```

it seems like there is a problem with `~/jhbuild/checkout`. Run

```
mkdir ~/jhbuild/checkout
```

if it not exists, and

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/jhbuild/checkout
```

to change the permmission, if necessary.

If official Ubuntu `docbook-xml` and `docbook-xsl` packages are already installed, another error can be probably removed by installing `xmlto`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xmlto
```